# Invalid node name gazeboo when trying to launch gazebo empty world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to launch an empty world in gazebo using the command

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

I encounter the error

```
Invalid node name [gazeboo/�]: node names cannot contain /
```

Is there a known fix for this issue?

---

The full error is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNodeNameException'
> what():  Invalid node name [gazeboo/�]: node names cannot contain /
> Msg Waiting for master
> Aborted (core dumped)
> Error [Connection.cc:477] Connection[0] Closed during Read
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
> what():  Connection reset by peer
> [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 18337, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/dhruv/.ros/log/6ed9ee8a-dde5-11e2-a0c6-0026c789069a/gazebo-2.log].
> log file: /home/dhruv/.ros/log/6ed9ee8a-dde5-11e2-a0c6-0026c789069a/gazebo-2*.log
> Aborted (core dumped)
> [gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 18346, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/dhruv/.ros/log/6ed9ee8a-dde5-11e2-a0c6-0026c789069a/gazebo_gui-3.log].
> log file: /home/dhruv/.ros/log/6ed9ee8a-dde5-11e2-a0c6-0026c789069a/gazebo_gui-3*.log

---

Launch file:

> 

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65938/invalid-node-name-gazeboo-when-trying-to-launch-gazebo-empty-world/) by [sunzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/5242/sunzun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-06-25**:
Did you try changing the node name ? Try re-naming the node name from its current value to something else, just 'gazebo' for instance. And also please update the question with your launch file.

**Comment by [sunzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/5242/sunzun/) on 2013-06-26**:
I believe the issue is in the ROS api for the gazebo. I haven't made any modifications to the standard groovy install for gazebo (I'm just attempting to run the launch file that ships with the package). I've posted the launch file.

**Comment by [sunzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/5242/sunzun/) on 2013-06-26**:
I would go through the source code myself, but it's thousands of lines of code, and a simply searching for "gazeboo" leads me to believe the issue is not as simple as a typo. Of course, I could be wrong, but I couldn't find where the issue was myself.

**Comment by [RC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1231/rc/) on 2013-06-26**:
I have the same problem, I hope to find the way to solve this.

**Comment by [fberger](https://answers.ros.org/users/15211/fberger/) on 2014-04-25**:
Did anyone resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, so there's apparently an issue with parsing the input argc/argv arguments when initializing the node in the file

> /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.src

I fixed this by explicitly defining the node name in the function

> void GazeboRosApiPlugin::Load(int argc, char** argv)

by replacing

> ros::init(argc,argv,"gazebo",ros::init_options::NoSigintHanlder);

with

> std::mapstd::string,std::string remappings;
> remappings["gazebo"] = "gazebo";
> ros::init(remappings,"gazebo",ros::init_options::NoSigintHanlder);

Probably not the most elegant solution, nor does it actually address the root cause of this issue, but it fixes the problem.

---

Originally posted by [sunzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/5242/sunzun/) with karma: 41 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [octavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5698/octavian/) on 2013-08-22**:
I had the same issue and tried your suggestion above. Do you perform a 'rosmake -a' afterwards in order to compile?

**Comment by [fberger](https://answers.ros.org/users/15211/fberger/) on 2014-04-25**:
Sunzun, are there any steps to do after editing the file? Also, are you editing gazebo_ros_api_plugin.src or gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp? Your instructions so far haven't gotten it to work for me...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought I'd explain Sunzun's solution with a bit more detail.

First edit: /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp

By replacing:

```
// setup ros related
if (!ros::isInitialized()) {
   ros::init(argc,argv,"gazebo",ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
 else 
    ROS_ERROR("Something other than this gazebo_ros_api plugin started ros::init(...), command line arguments may not be parsed properly.");
```

with:

```
// setup ros related
if (!ros::isInitialized()) {
    std::map<std::string,std::string> remappings; 
     remappings["gazebo"] = "gazebo"; 
     ros::init(remappings,"gazebo",ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
  } else {
    ROS_ERROR("Something other than this gazebo_ros_api plugin started ros::init(...), command line arguments may not be parsed properly.");
  }
```

It is important to add the brackets around the if and else statement since we now have multiple instructions within the if statement clause.

Now, in order to re-compile the package with the changes, this is perhaps a little bit of a hack but you need to first delete the ROS_NOBUILD file from within /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo This will tell rosmake to recompile this package.

If you attempt to run rosmake simulator_gazebo, you will get a permission denied error, so now you need to temporarily change the ownership of the simulator_gazebo package.

```
sudo chown -R %YOUR_USER_NAME%: simulator_gazebo
```

Now you should be able to run:

```
rosmake simulator_gazebo
```

And it should re-compile your changes to the file!

Now, run:

```
 roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

and Enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [fberger](https://answers.ros.org/users/15211/fberger/) with karma: 11 on 2014-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1